# What's the best way excluding a query set from a queryset

Tags: python, django

I'm writing an inbox view and I want to exclude unseen messages from seen messages.
My code is :

> def render_notifications(request):
>
> ```
>  unseen_notices = notification.Notice.objects.filter(recipient=request.user,unseen=True).order_by("-added")
>  notices = notification.Notice.objects.filter(recipient=request.user).exclude(id__in = [i.id for i in unseen_notices]).order_by("-added")
>
>  for msg in unseen_notices:
>      msg.unseen = False
>      msg.save()
>
>  context = RequestContext(request,{'notices':notices,
>                 'unseen_notices':unseen_notices})
>  return render_to_response('my_notifications.html',context_instance=context)
> ```

As you can see I exclude all unseen messages using a for loop which doesn't seem convenient and I'm not sure but does this line cause performance issues ? And lastly is there a way that I can replace this line with something similar to :

> notices = notification.Notice.objects.filter(recipient=request.user).exclude(id__in =unseen_messages)

**Edit:**

I can't get **seen messages** correctly with using **unseen = False** , because I mark all unseen messages as seen when the page is visited. With a strange reason when I use unseen = False in **notices** query, all marked unseen messages are retrieved from notices query.

Comment: Just curious, could you not filter by `unseen=False`? i.e. `notices = notification.Notice.objects.filter(receipient=request.user,unseen=False)...`

Comment: If I do that the unseen messages will be marked as seen and don't know why but they become visible in notices query-set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Django querysets are lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy). This explains why the 'unseen' notices appear in the seen notices list when you follow Derek's suggestion the comments above. The notices query is not executed until the template is rendered when you call `render_to_response`. By this timetime you have already saved the msg as seen.

If you call `list()` on your querysets, they are evaluated immediately, and the 'unseen' notifications will no longer appear in the seen notices.

```
def render_notifications(request):
    user_notices = notification.Notice.objects.filter(recipient=request.user).order_by(-'added')
    unseen_notices = list(user_notices.filter(unseen=True))
    notices = list(user_notices.filter(unseen=False))
    <snip>
```

An alternative is to render the response, then update the `unseen` flag on the notifications, then finally return the response.

```
def render_notifications(request):
    user_notices = notification.Notice.objects.filter(recipient=request.user).order_by(-'added')
    unseen_notices = user_notices.filter(unseen=True)
    notices = user_notices.filter(unseen=False)

    context = RequestContext(request,{'notices':notices,
            'unseen_notices':unseen_notices})
    response = render_to_response('my_notifications.html',context_instance=context)

    # update the seen flag
    unseen_notices.update(unseen=False)

    return response
```

Note that I've used [`update`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once) method of the queryset instead of looping through each notice. You can't do this if your model has a custom save method or if you are using written pre/post save hooks.

Answer (score 1):

Seem that you can do something like here:

```
 user_notices = notification.Notice.objects.filter(recipient=request.user)
 unseen_notices = user_notices.filter(unseen=True).order_by("-added")
 notices = user_notices.exclude(unseen=True).order_by("-added")
```

Comment: +1 Setting `user_notices` avoids repeating the recipient filter. You can put the `order_by` call on the `user_notices` queryset to make it even DRYer.